# Get Companies API in Microsoft Business central

Tags: dynamics-business-central

I am trying to integrate Salesforce with Business central. I am totally new to business central and learend hot to hit BC API.
So created application in Azure AD, and in BC have configured Azure Active Directory Application Card also and gave full permision also

[image]

and when I tried to get the get companies with the API
https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v2.0/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Production/api/v1.0/companies

I am getting only below response in postman and not sure why other companies are not coming.

[image]